# Unity on Android .SVG to .PNG conversion

Tags: c#, android, svg, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert a `.svg` file to a raster image (.png) at runtime, to render it in my Unity program, on Android :)

The best solution I found is to use this [lib](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG)

Though, I added the `.Dll` (called "Svg") and this little code :

```
Svg.SvgDocument doc = Svg.SvgDocument.Open(filename);
```

With this little line, Unity tells me :

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Svg.SvgElement' from assembly 'Svg, Version=0.5.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.MonoType:GetMethodsByName
>   (string,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,bool,System.Type)
>
> at System.MonoType.GetMethods (BindingFlags bindingAttr) [0x00000]
>   in :0
>
> etc...

I guess it's a DLL usage / import problem ? I am not really used to DLL / plugin usage in Unity... I ask the question here since I didn't find anything on the net :/

Do you have a proper way to draw my .svg on unity android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin to convert SVG to PNG at build time so your application only rely on PNG of various density : https://github.com/avianey/androidsvgdrawable-plugin

It is integrated with the gradle build system (and the maven one as well)

Answer (score 0):

@Loïs As far as I have come with this problem I think the linked asset: [svg api](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG)
is no good for converting .svg to .png on Andrid, becouse it depends on System.Drawing.Commons which throws exceptions when used on android.
But I am very much interested if you ever found a solution for this.